# How to verify, that a DB hive already exists?

Tags: linux, expect, postgresql, apache-hive

We create a hive database using expect script and with some other commands.

In the case if we run the expect script again on the machine that hive already created, we get this:

> ERROR hive already exists

How can we check if *database hive already created* before creating it again?

And by this verification we can escape the *expect script*:

```
# su - postgres
 Last login: Sun Aug 13 11:12:03 UTC 2017 on pts/0
 -bash-4.2$ psql
 psql (9.2.13)
 Type "help" for help.

postgres=# CREATE DATABASE hive;
ERROR:  database "hive" already exists
```

My expect script: (from my bash script)

```
set timeout -1

#exec the scripts

spawn timeout 60 ssh root@IP
expect "#"
spawn su - postgres
expect "$"
send "psql\n"
expect "=#"
send "CREATE DATABASE hive;\n"
.
.
.
.
```

Other example:

```
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE [IF NOT EXISTS] hive;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
LINE 1: CREATE DATABASE [IF NOT EXISTS] hive;
                    ^
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/45659905/4957508

Comment: I suggest to check the rules, when should you use "the" or "a". It would significantly improve your English (it doesn't make your posts incomprehensible, but anybody having a first language with articles, will have to think about what you tried to say. So you lose a lot of good answers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to use Hive database, try [using hive directly](http://peter.eisentraut.org/blog/2015/08/14/have-problems-with-postgresql-try-using-hive/) (see below)

**PostgreSQL answer**

Stack overflow Q&A [Simulate CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS for PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18389124/5088142)

Specify that PostgreSQL doesn't have build in support for *IF NOT EXISTS* (as hive have)

One of the simple answer mentioned there is: query the database, and only if the query fail - create the database.

> ```
> psql -U postgres -tc "SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'my_db'" | grep -q 1 || psql -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE my_db"
> ```

**Hive answer:**

You should use the command with the option **[IF NOT EXISTS]**:

```
CREATE DATABASE [IF NOT EXISTS] <database name>
```

[More info](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hive/hive_create_database.htm)

> **Create Database Statement**
>
> Create Database is a statement used to create a database in Hive. A
>   database in Hive is a namespace or a collection of tables. The syntax
>   for this statement is as follows:
>
> ```
> CREATE DATABASE|SCHEMA [IF NOT EXISTS] <database name>
> ```
>
> Here, IF NOT EXISTS is an optional clause, which notifies the user
>   that a database with the same name already exists. We can use SCHEMA
>   in place of DATABASE in this command. The following query is executed
>   to create a database named userdb:
>
> ```
> hive> CREATE DATABASE [IF NOT EXISTS] userdb;
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> hive> CREATE SCHEMA userdb;
> ```

Comment: hi yaron , I create the hive DB from postgres not from hive

Comment: @yael - why won't you create hive DB using `hive`?

Comment: see the other example in my question

Comment: @yael - why won't you create hive DB using `hive` instead of using `postgres`?

Comment: because this is the code ( I only want to improve it in case of second running

Comment: is there any other option only from postgres ?

Comment: @yae - I've updated my answer to include two options - one using **PostgreSQL** and one with **hive**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63746/discussion-between-yael-and-yaron).